# How to prevent Firefox from trimming the URLs on the address bar?

Tags: firefox

At some point fairly recently, the URLs shown in the Firefox location bar dropped the protocol prefix -- urls appear as "askubuntu.com" not "http://askubuntu.com" -- if the site is https://... the prefix does appear, but I'd like to see it all the time.

How do I get that back?

Comment: Note that with version 8, copying the URL from the address bar the `http://` prefix is actually copied, event though not displayed. Thus I can live with it not being displayed. In version 7 however, it is _not_ copied, which is a major annoyance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its considered a "feature" since version 7.

To turn it off type on the address bar `about:config`, look for ***browser.urlbar.trimURLs*** and set the value to **false**.

Comment: ...Emphasis on the quotes around "feature"...

Comment: As someone who teaches people how to use computers and the internet, this is part of an exasperating trend. It makes it just a little harder to walk students through the anatomy of a URL.

Comment: @lzkata As with many features, some people like it and some people don't. My dad would still be using Windows 3.1 if he could be, he hates change so much.